# Getting the top values by group

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Here's a sample data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(
  x   = runif(90),
  grp = gl(3, 30)
)
```

I want the subset of `d` containing the rows with the top 5 values of `x` for each value of `grp`.

Using base-R, my approach would be something like:

```
ordered <- d[order(d$x, decreasing = TRUE), ]    
splits <- split(ordered, ordered$grp)
heads <- lapply(splits, head)
do.call(rbind, heads)
##              x grp
## 1.19 0.8879631   1
## 1.4  0.8844818   1
## 1.12 0.8596197   1
## 1.26 0.8481809   1
## 1.18 0.8461516   1
## 1.29 0.8317092   1
## 2.31 0.9751049   2
## 2.34 0.9269764   2
## 2.57 0.8964114   2
## 2.58 0.8896466   2
## 2.45 0.8888834   2
## 2.35 0.8706823   2
## 3.74 0.9884852   3
## 3.73 0.9837653   3
## 3.83 0.9375398   3
## 3.64 0.9229036   3
## 3.69 0.8021373   3
## 3.86 0.7418946   3
```

Using `dplyr`, I expected this to work:

```
d %>%
  arrange_(~ desc(x)) %>%
  group_by_(~ grp) %>%
  head(n = 5)
```

but it only returns the overall top 5 rows.

Swapping `head` for [`top_n`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/dplyr/docs/top_n) returns the whole of `d`.

```
d %>%
  arrange_(~ desc(x)) %>%
  group_by_(~ grp) %>%
  top_n(n = 5)
```

How do I get the correct subset?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

From [dplyr 1.0.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md), "`slice_min()` and `slice_max()` select the rows with the minimum or maximum values of a variable, taking over from the confusing `top_n().`"

```
d %>% group_by(grp) %>% slice_max(order_by = x, n = 5)
# # A tibble: 15 x 2
# # Groups:   grp [3]
#     x grp  
# <dbl> <fct>
#  1 0.994 1    
#  2 0.957 1    
#  3 0.955 1    
#  4 0.940 1    
#  5 0.900 1    
#  6 0.963 2    
#  7 0.902 2    
#  8 0.895 2    
#  9 0.858 2    
# 10 0.799 2    
# 11 0.985 3    
# 12 0.893 3    
# 13 0.886 3    
# 14 0.815 3    
# 15 0.812 3
```

---

Pre-`dplyr 1.0.0` using `top_n`:

From `?top_n`, about the `wt` argument:

> The variable to use for ordering [...] **defaults to the last variable** in the tbl".

The last variable in your data set is "grp", which is not the variable you wish to rank, and which is why your `top_n` attempt "returns the whole of d". Thus, if you wish to rank by "x" in your data set, you need to specify `wt = x`.

```
d %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  top_n(n = 5, wt = x)
```

---

#### Data:

```
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(
  x = runif(90),
  grp = gl(3, 30))
```

Answer (score 45):

Pretty easy with `data.table` too...

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(d), -x)[, head(.SD, 5), keyby = grp]
```

Or

```
setorder(setDT(d), grp, -x)[, head(.SD, 5), by = grp]
```

Or (Should be faster for big data set because avoiding calling `.SD` for each group)

```
setorder(setDT(d), grp, -x)[, indx := seq_len(.N), by = grp][indx <= 5]
```

---

**Edit:** Here's how `dplyr` compares to `data.table` (if anyone's interested)

```
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(
  x   = runif(1e6),
  grp = sample(1e4, 1e6, TRUE))

library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
dd <- copy(d)

microbenchmark(
  top_n = {d %>%
             group_by(grp) %>%
             top_n(n = 5, wt = x)},
  dohead = {d %>%
              arrange_(~ desc(x)) %>%
              group_by_(~ grp) %>%
              do(head(., n = 5))},
  slice = {d %>%
             arrange_(~ desc(x)) %>%
             group_by_(~ grp) %>%
             slice(1:5)},
  filter = {d %>% 
              arrange(desc(x)) %>%
              group_by(grp) %>%
              filter(row_number() <= 5L)},
  data.table1 = setorder(setDT(dd), -x)[, head(.SD, 5L), keyby = grp],
  data.table2 = setorder(setDT(dd), grp, -x)[, head(.SD, 5L), grp],
  data.table3 = setorder(setDT(dd), grp, -x)[, indx := seq_len(.N), grp][indx <= 5L],
  times = 10,
  unit = "relative"
)


#        expr        min         lq      mean     median        uq       max neval
#       top_n  24.246401  24.492972 16.300391  24.441351 11.749050  7.644748    10
#      dohead 122.891381 120.329722 77.763843 115.621635 54.996588 34.114738    10
#       slice  27.365711  26.839443 17.714303  26.433924 12.628934  7.899619    10
#      filter  27.755171  27.225461 17.936295  26.363739 12.935709  7.969806    10
# data.table1  13.753046  16.631143 10.775278  16.330942  8.359951  5.077140    10
# data.table2  12.047111  11.944557  7.862302  11.653385  5.509432  3.642733    10
# data.table3   1.000000   1.000000  1.000000   1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    10
```

---

Adding a marginally faster `data.table` solution:

```
set.seed(123L)
d <- data.frame(
    x   = runif(1e8),
    grp = sample(1e4, 1e8, TRUE))
setDT(d)
setorder(d, grp, -x)
dd <- copy(d)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    data.table3 = d[, indx := seq_len(.N), grp][indx <= 5L],
    data.table4 = dd[dd[, .I[seq_len(.N) <= 5L], grp]$V1],
    times = 10L
)
```

timing output:

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
 data.table3 826.2148 865.6334 950.1380 902.1689 1006.1237 1260.129    10
 data.table4 729.3229 783.7000 859.2084 823.1635  966.8239 1014.397    10
```

Comment: Adding another `data.table` method which should be slightly faster: `dt <- setorder(setDT(dd), grp, -x); dt[dt[, .I[seq_len(.N) <= 5L], grp]$V1]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 be my guest. I don't have time to benchmark these solutions again.

Comment: Adding another `data.table` method easier : `setDT(d)[order(-x),x[1:5],keyby = .(grp)]`

Comment: @TaoHu it's pretty much like the first two solutions. I don't think `:` will beat `head`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah，I agree with you,I think the most difference is `setorder` faster than `order`

Answer (score 36):

You need to wrap `head` in a call to [`do`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/dplyr/docs/do).  In the following code, `.` represents the current group (see description of `...` in the `do` help page).

```
d %>%
  arrange_(~ desc(x)) %>%
  group_by_(~ grp) %>%
  do(head(., n = 5))
```

---

As mentioned by akrun, `slice` is an alternative.

```
d %>%
  arrange_(~ desc(x)) %>%
  group_by_(~ grp) %>%
  slice(1:5)
```

---

Though I didn't ask this, for completeness, a possible `data.table` version is (thanks to @Arun for the fix):

```
setDT(d)[order(-x), head(.SD, 5), by = grp]
```

Comment: Richie, FWIW you just need a small addition: `setDT(d)[order(-x), head(.SD, 5L), by=grp]`

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated but the second part is the idomatic way if you drop the `~` and use `arrange` and `group_by` instead of `arrange_` and `group_by_`

Answer (score 18):

My approach in base R would be:

```
ordered <- d[order(d$x, decreasing = TRUE), ]
ordered[ave(d$x, d$grp, FUN = seq_along) <= 5L,]
```

And using dplyr, the approach with `slice` is probably fastest, but you could also use `filter` which will likely be faster than using `do(head(., 5))`:

```
d %>% 
  arrange(desc(x)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 5L)
```

#### dplyr benchmark

```
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(
  x   = runif(1e6),
  grp = sample(1e4, 1e6, TRUE))

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  top_n = {d %>%
             group_by(grp) %>%
             top_n(n = 5, wt = x)},
  dohead = {d %>%
              arrange_(~ desc(x)) %>%
              group_by_(~ grp) %>%
              do(head(., n = 5))},
  slice = {d %>%
             arrange_(~ desc(x)) %>%
             group_by_(~ grp) %>%
             slice(1:5)},
  filter = {d %>% 
              arrange(desc(x)) %>%
              group_by(grp) %>%
              filter(row_number() <= 5L)},
  times = 10,
  unit = "relative"
)

Unit: relative
   expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
  top_n  1.042735  1.075366  1.082113  1.085072  1.000846    10
 dohead 18.663825 19.342854 19.511495 19.840377 17.433518    10
  slice  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    10
 filter  1.048556  1.044113  1.042184  1.180474  1.053378    10
```

Comment: Nice R base approach!

Answer (score 2):

top_n(n = 1) will still return multiple rows for each group if the *ordering* variable is not unique within each group. In order to select precisely one occurence for each group, add an unique variable to each row:

```
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(
  x   = runif(90),
  grp = gl(3, 30))

d %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  top_n(n = 1, wt = rn)
```

Comment: This only return the max value of your rn column(30,60,90) not the max value of x group by grp. using your seed and the answer from the top with parameter n=1 we have: [x grp],[0.994 1][0.963 2] [0.985 3]
In your case [x grp rn][0.147 1 30] [0.374 2 60]
[0.175 3 90] just the values corresponding to rn column.

Answer (score 0):

One more `data.table` solution to highlight its concise syntax:

```
setDT(d)
d[order(-x), .SD[1:5], grp]
```