# r - select last n occurrences for each group

Tags: r

**Situation**

I have a data frame `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(person = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L), .Label = c("pA", "pB", "pC"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(16071, 
    16102, 16130, 16161, 16071, 16102, 16130, 16071, 16102), class = "Date")), .Names = c("person", 
    "date"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

> df
  person       date
1     pA 2014-01-01
2     pA 2014-02-01
3     pA 2014-03-01
4     pA 2014-04-01
5     pB 2014-01-01
6     pB 2014-02-01
7     pB 2014-03-01
8     pC 2014-01-01
9     pC 2014-02-01
```

**Question**

How can I select the last 2 (or 'n') entries, ordered by date, for each person, so that I have a resulting data frame `df1`:

```
> df1
  person       date
1     pA 2014-03-01
2     pA 2014-04-01
3     pB 2014-02-01
4     pB 2014-03-01
5     pC 2014-01-01
6     pC 2014-02-01
```

?

I've tried combinations of

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
    group_by(person) %>% 
    select(tail(df, 2))
```

with no joy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(person) %>% 
    arrange(date, person) %>%
    slice((n()-1):n())
#  person       date
#1     pA 2014-03-01
#2     pA 2014-04-01
#3     pB 2014-02-01
#4     pB 2014-03-01
#5     pC 2014-01-01
#6     pC 2014-02-01
```

Or in place of the last step

```
   do(tail(., 2))
```

Comment: @tospig `do` is useful, but I would think `slice` to be faster.

Comment: I am using `dplyr_0.4.0`.  which version of dplyr you have ?

Comment: Ah yes, I was on `0.2` - have updated now to `0.4.1` and it works.

Comment: And `slice` is faster on my actual data set (`1600 rows x 16 variables`)

Answer (score 6):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[order(person), tail(.SD, 2L), by=person]
#    person       date
# 1:     pA 2014-03-01
# 2:     pA 2014-04-01
# 3:     pB 2014-02-01
# 4:     pB 2014-03-01
# 5:     pC 2014-01-01
# 6:     pC 2014-02-01
```

We *order* by `person` and then *group by* `person` and select the last two rows from the subset of data `.SD` for each group.

Comment: For some reason I've stayed away from learning `data.table` syntax. Maybe I should start to learn.

Comment: You can start with [these vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944).

Answer (score 3):

Since you order the data by person and date (i.e. you want the 2 latest dates per person), you can also use `top_n()` in dplyr:

```
df %>% group_by(person) %>% top_n(2, date)
#Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
#Groups: person
#
#  person       date
#1     pA 2014-03-01
#2     pA 2014-04-01
#3     pB 2014-02-01
#4     pB 2014-03-01
#5     pC 2014-01-01
#6     pC 2014-02-01
```

Or, if you already order it, you could arrange it the other way before using slice:

```
df %>% arrange(person, desc(date)) %>% group_by(person) %>% slice(1:2)
#Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
#Groups: person
#
#  person       date
#1     pA 2014-04-01
#2     pA 2014-03-01
#3     pB 2014-03-01
#4     pB 2014-02-01
#5     pC 2014-02-01
#6     pC 2014-01-01
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27766197/3521006) for a benchmark of a similar question.