# Sort a list by value while retaining numeric key in R

Tags: r

I know this is a common question, but the common answer of `r[order(unlist(r))]` isn't working due to numerical keys. I can't find any answers after a while of searching. I did see [How can I get top n values with its index in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565788/how-can-i-get-top-n-values-with-its-index-in-r) but that uses a dataframe, and I don't know how to implement a dataframe into my function.

I have a list of values which I created by using r[[i]] <- `value` within a loop. Now I want to sort that list, but keep the numerical key.

```
> r
[[1]]
[1] 4396750

[[2]]
[1] 6340260

[[3]]
[1] 8449058

[[4]]
[1] 5676146

> r <- r[order(unlist(r))]
> r
[[1]]
[1] 4396750

[[2]]
[1] 5676146

[[3]]
[1] 6340260

[[4]]
[1] 8449058
```

I need some way to retain the keys, so that I know the values, from lowest to highest, are represented by keys `1,4,2,3`. Then I will need to keep the keys with the lowest 3 values. So my end result should be some list or vector that gives me `1,4,2`.

My example is simplified, so doing some shortcut like "just drop the highest value" won't work.

The actual code for the function is here:

```
knnacc <- function(e){
  dist = list()
  for(j in 1:10000) {
    dist[[j]] <- distance(TEST[["image"]][[e]], TRAIN[["image"]][[j]])
  }
  #dist <- dist[order(unlist(dist))]
  return(dist)
}
```

I would like to reach a point where the function returns the 20 keys associated with lowest distance out of 60,000.

Comment: Are you looking for `order(unlist(r))[1:3]` ?

Comment: I'd suggest using more meaningful list names. Or putting it in data frame with an "id" column and a "value" column. Maybe a `list` column if there are additional list compnents you're not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'numerical keys' are simply the index in the list. To retain the original indices in a sorted list, you might simply add names to your list elements based on those original indices.

E.g.,

```
r = list(4396750, 6340260, 8449058, 5676146)
#> r
#[[1]]
#[1] 4396750
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 6340260
# 
#[[3]]
#[1] 8449058
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 5676146  

names(r) <- as.character(1:length(r))

r <- r[order(unlist(r))]

#> r
#$`1`
#[1] 4396750
#
#$`4`
#[1] 5676146
#
#$`2`
#[1] 6340260
#
#$`3`
#[1] 8449058
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd like a `list` rather than a `vector`.
Having the following dummy variable, try:

```
> r
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 10

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 3

setNames(r[order(unlist(r))],order(unlist(r)))
$`1`
[1] 1

$`3`
[1] 2

$`5`
[1] 3

$`4`
[1] 4

$`2`
[1] 10
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me, but the other answer did.

Comment: it is part of the `stats` package, maybe you do not have it in your global environment?