# Getting the top n values by group not working as expected

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider the following head(10) of a dataframe:

[image: Consider the following head(10) of a dataframe]

It is generated by this dplyr code:

```
Fuller_list %>% 
 as.data.frame() %>% 
 select(from_infomap, topic) %>%
 add_count(from_infomap) %>% 
 filter(from_infomap %in% coms_keep) %>% 
 group_by(from_infomap) %>%
 add_count(topic) %>%
 top_n(10, nn) %>%
 head(10)
```

There are 36 different communities in the "from_infomap" column and 47 different topics in the "topic" column. Grouped by "from_infomap" the number of topics per community, for the first 5 communities, look like this:

[image] 
I would like to show the top 10 most occurring topics per community, ordered descending. I tried to do that here with:

```
 group_by(from_infomap) %>%
 add_count(topic) %>%
 top_n(10, nn)
```

But if I plot that, it only returns the top 1 topic per community:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766054/getting-the-top-values-by-group) stack overflow query, the weighted top_n(n,wt) function on the count should work, it should give the top 10 topics weighted by their count, grouped by community.

If anyone could perhaps suggest an alternative or point out where I'm going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. Apologies for the small screenshots, I can't show the entire data.frame here, as it is quite large.

Thanks!

Edit: dput without the group_by, add_count and top_n:

```
n <- Fuller_list %>% 
 as.data.frame() %>% 
 select(from_infomap, topic) %>%
 add_count(from_infomap) %>% 
 filter(from_infomap %in% coms_keep) %>% 
 group_by(from_infomap)
```

dput(head(n,10)):

```
structure(list(from_infomap = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), topic = c("KnysnaFire_thanks_wofire", "Abramjee_caperelief_operationsa", 
"Pick_n_Pay", "Plett_heavy_rain_snow", "Disasters_help_call", 
"KFM_disasters_discussion", "Pick_n_Pay", "Pick_n_Pay", "Pick_n_Pay", 
"Pick_n_Pay"), n = c(30512L, 30512L, 30512L, 6572L, 6572L, 6572L, 
5030L, 5030L, 5030L, 5030L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "from_infomap", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:2, 3:5, 6:9), group_sizes = c(3L, 3L, 4L), biggest_group_size = 4L, labels = structure(list(
    from_infomap = c(1L, 3L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame", vars = "from_infomap", drop = TRUE))
```

Issue should be reproducible by adding this code to the previous chunk:

```
  add_count(topic) %>%
  top_n(10,nn) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(topic,nn),y = nn,fill = from_infomap))+
  geom_col(width = 1)+
  facet_wrap(~from_infomap, scales = "free")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text("Central Players"), 
        plot.subtitle= element_text("Top 10 indegree centrality profiles of the 20 biggest communities.\n Excluding 'starburst' communities."),
        plot.caption = element_text("Source: Twitter"))+
  theme_few()
```

Halway-Solution: So with the summarise method suggested by @s_t, we have the following code:

```
Fuller_list %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  add_count(from_infomap) %>%
  filter(from_infomap %in% coms_keep) %>% 
  group_by(from_infomap,topic) %>%   # group by the topic and community
  summarise(nn = n()) %>%            # count the mentioned arguments
  top_n(10, nn) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(from_infomap, nn) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(topic,nn),y = nn,fill = from_infomap))+
  geom_col(width = 1)+
  facet_wrap(~from_infomap, scales = "free")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text("Central Players"), 
        plot.subtitle= element_text("Top 10 indegree centrality profiles of the 20 biggest communities.\n Excluding 'starburst' communities."),
        plot.caption = element_text("Source: Twitter"))+
  theme_few()
```

And this produces: [image]

Which is the correct top_n(10) of the various communities. For all practical purposes, the plot now shows the correct data. The only remaining issue is that the arrange does not sort the various topics in desc order *per community*, but rather overall. Minor issue, would only improve aes if the topics could be arranged per community.

Comment: Could you post some usable data (not an image)?

Comment: Here are some tips on how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: @s_t I've added a link to a downloadable sample of the code. I hope this is what you were looking for? https://drive.google.com/file/d/128R9Vgjd2QsFwHf0M5Yi8ltli2dsDsrJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @snoram, I would like to use dput to give a sample of the code, but the dataset is quite large (many variables), it won't be practically viewable here. I've provided a link to a 1000 line sample, I hope this is in order?

Comment: @Petrus, I really do not want to be pedantic, and I appreciate your attempt, but it's not a good practice to put data to download: if you post the result of `dput(head(your_data,10))`  (that is in the image I suppose, or more rows to have significant data) it's going to be better.

Comment: @Petrus select just the relevawnt variables, and the first few rows using head as s_t suggests

Comment: @s_t Of course, I've added the output from dput(head()) below. Is that what you were looking for? Apologies, I'm not very experienced at this yet.

Comment: Not a problem! Your code seems working removing  `%>% head(10)` , using fake bigger data similar to yours: are you sure that maybe you are forgetting to remove `%>% head(10)` or, in other hands,is it necessary?

Comment: @s_t That's strange, I didn't have ```%>% head(10) ``` in the code I generated the dput. I just generated it from the code chunk I listed first. Let me generate it without the group_by, add_count and top_n(10, nn) and add that sample. You should be able to see the effect of group_by, add_count and top_n(10, nn) when it's added to the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help, if I've understood well, you would like to count the topics in each community, select the top(X), and plot them in a decreasing way in each facet:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data3 <-
  data2 %>%
  select(-n) %>%                     # remove useless column
  group_by(from_infomap,topic) %>%   # group by the topic and community
  summarise(nn = n()) %>%            # count the mentioned arguments
  top_n(5, nn)                       # take the top 5 in this case
```

Now we handle the order, as stated [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1902):

```
data4 <- data3 %>% 
         ungroup() %>%  
         arrange(from_infomap, nn) %>%  
         mutate(topic_r = row_number())
```

Lastly the plot:

```
ggplot(data4, aes(topic_r, nn,fill = from_infomap)) + 
geom_col() +
facet_wrap(~ from_infomap, scales = "free") +
scale_x_continuous(  
                   breaks = d$topic_r,  
                   labels = d$topic
                  ) +
coord_flip()
```

[image]

I have used some fake data, like these:

```
data2 <- data.frame(from_infomap =floor(runif(200, 1,5)) ,
                    topic = sample(letters[1:20], 200, TRUE),
                    n = floor(runif(200, 10,50)) )
```

So many topics in communities have the same number, so you do not see only 5 columns.

Comment: This is definitely a move in the right direction, I'm getting multiple topics per community now. I'm just getting a plot for every row though, but I'm going to work with this and get back to you with a solution. Thank you so much for your effort!

Comment: If you remove the useless part in your question ad update it with this answer, we can try to solve everything if there are other issues.

Comment: I've added a "Halfway-Solution" to the question with your code added. Only remaining issue is the arrange that is applied overall, rather than per community. However, I'm more than happy to have the correct representation of data on the plot already. Thank you very much!

Comment: Looking at your new code, you have forgot the some steps of my `data4` , like `mutate(...)` that adds the variable to use in the plot,  and the `scale_x_continuous(...)` part in the plot, to order the bars.

Comment: I tried to add the mutate() for topic_r and then the scale_x_continuous to the plot, but got the error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale. I tried several solutions, such as scale_x_discrete, or coercing topic_r into a numeric value as suggested by a different stackoverflow question, but didn't succeed.

Comment: My advice is to arrive to have your data as my data2, then try to use al the code step by step. Ordering in ggplot imho is not so simple.