# dplyr: top_n function does not filter rows when used with group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr

could not get top_n function to work on my data and the following does not seem to pull the top 5 rows as suggested in [help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/top_n)

```
library(dplyr)
data("iris")

df <- iris %>%
  filter(Petal.Width>1) %>% 
  group_by(Petal.Width, Species)%>% 
  summarize(n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(n) %>% 
  top_n(5)
dim(df)
```

Comment: You could use `ungroup()` after `arrange(n)`. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766054/getting-the-top-values-by-group)

Comment: You are slicing the top 5 rows from each group. As @GooJ suggested, use `ungroup()` before `top_n(5)`.