# dplyr select top 10 values for each category

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter a data frame that contains n rows for n categories.
I want that each category `dimension` values are sorted by another column `revenues` and then, the top 10 values of each `dimension` are selected and get rid of the rest.

I did an attempt with the following snippet, but it does not seem to achieve what I want to:

```
data <-  tbl_df(data) %>%
  arrange(revenues) %>%
  group_by(dimension) %>%
  top_n(10)
```

Comment: could you share the source of error ? Otherwise we won't be able to help you

Comment: I don't get an error. I am just not getting the desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the top values by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766054/getting-the-top-values-by-group)

Comment: It seems to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766054/getting-the-top-values-by-group).  When posting a question I would recommend avoiding putting `dplyr` at the front of the title unless you are a master of `dplyr`. It might save you having to write the question entirely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select the top N values by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800161/select-the-top-n-values-by-group)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data <-  tbl_df(data) %>%
  group_by(dimension) %>%
  arrange(revenues, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  top_n(10)
```

Comment: You need to specify which column to be ordered by in `top_n()`, or it'll take the default to the last variable in the data.

Comment: For late comers,  `top_n` has been **superceded** by `slice_min` or `slice_max` to be clear on order. Not threatened to be deprecated as at dplyr 1.0.10. 
Safer syntax for future would be `slice_max(revenues, n = 10)`  for ten largest revenues and for smallest ones use `slice_min`.  Slice has a number of alternatives. You can also slice on existing database order `slice_head`, or if you wanted a random sample tilted to bigger revenue items, assuming replacement ,`slice_sample(n =  10, replace = TRUE, weight_by = revenues)`.

Answer (score 2):

We can test it with an example data:

```
set.seed(100)
data = data.frame(revenues=rnbinom(100,mu=1000,size=1),
dimension=sample(letters[1:2],100,replace=TRUE))
```

Firstly as @DarrenTsai correctly pointed out, you need to specify the column to do top_n(). Secondly, when you use top_n, it goes by descending order and takes the entries with rank 1-10:

```
data %>% top_n(10,revenues)
   revenues dimension
1      4191         b
2      1916         a
3      2397         b
4      1895         a
5      2013         a
6      2351         b
7      3889         b
8      2503         a
9      3909         a
10     2779         b
```

This means you don't need to arrange your data, and I am not sure whether you intend to take it in descending or ascending. Let's assume it is descending, :

```
data %>%  group_by(dimension) %>% top_n(10,revenues)
```

Note, this code above will take the top 10 values, meaning in events of ties (say you have 2 ranked 1st), you will get more than 10. For example in this data:

```
# A tibble: 21 x 2
# Groups:   dimension [2]
   revenues dimension
      <dbl> <fct>    
 1     1663 a        
 2     1663 a        
 3     1753 a        
 4     1849 a        
 5     1856 a        
 6     1869 a        
 7     1895 a        
 8     1916 a        
 9     2013 a        
10     2503 a        
# … with 11 more rows
```

We can see whether the results are correct, this is what we expect:

```
unlist(tapply(data$revenues,data$dimension,function(i)-sort(-i)[1:10]))
  a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6   a7   a8   a9  a10   b1   b2   b3   b4   b5   b6 
3909 2503 2013 1916 1895 1869 1856 1849 1753 1663 4191 3889 2779 2397 2351 1479 
  b7   b8   b9  b10 
1414 1340 1327 1274
```

And using the `group_by + top_n()` :

```
 data %>%  group_by(dimension) %>% top_n(10,revenues) %>% 
arrange(dimension,desc(revenues)) %>% pull(revenues)
 [1] 3909 2503 2013 1916 1895 1869 1856 1849 1753 1663 1663 4191 3889 2779 2397
[16] 2351 1479 1414 1340 1327 1274
```

You can see 1663 is taken twice, giving 21 values in total.

If you need absolutely 20 (10 each):

```
data %>% arrange(desc(revenues)) %>%
group_by(dimension) %>% do(head(.,10))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data <-  tbl_df(data) %>%
  group_by(dimension) %>%
  arrange(desc(revenues),.by_group=TRUE) %>%
  top_n(10,revenues)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for your sharing your answer. To make your answer complete It is essential  you add some explanation to your answer, Feel free give some identify what was the issue with the original post.

Comment: Thank you and I shall keep in mind to add necessary explanation going forward.